# Pull in current month/year and previous month/year in Ruby

Tags: ruby, date

I am creating a 12 month line chart that has data for the previous 12 months. The current month, or 12th line item, should say `OCT 13`. The first line item should say `OCT 12`.

How can I write something to dynamically pull in the current month as well as the previous 11 months, all the way back to the current month in last year. The issue I am having is making sure that last October gets tagged as a month in 2012, but in 3 months I need January to be tagged as 2013 without me changing the code.

Comment: If you have a list of every months starting from October 2012 to October 2013, then you would have a list of 13 elements, not 12. The current month would not be the 12th item (index 11), but would be the 13th (index 12).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [**`<<`**](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0.0/libdoc/date/rdoc/Date.html#method-i-3C-3C) operator to shift date by a month

```
require "date"

12.downto(0).map{ |d| (Date.today <<  d).strftime("%^b %y") } 
#=> ["OCT 12", "NOV 12", "DEC 12", "JAN 13", "FEB 13", "MAR 13", "APR 13",
#     "MAY 13", "JUN 13", "JUL 13", "AUG 13", "SEP 13", "OCT 13"]
```

Used @Stefan's input to change the order.

Comment: Or simply `(Date.today << d).strftime("%b %Y")` and maybe `12.downto(0)`

Comment: @Stefan good suggestion...I keep the order as it is as it depend on what order OP wants.

Comment: *"The first line item should say OCT 12"*

Answer (score 2):

```
a = [Date.today.prev_year]
12.times{a.push(a.last.next_month)}
a.map{|d| d.strftime("%^b %y")}

# => [
  "OCT 12",
  "NOV 12",
  "DEC 12",
  "JAN 13",
  "FEB 13",
  "MAR 13",
  "APR 13",
  "MAY 13",
  "JUN 13",
  "JUL 13",
  "AUG 13",
  "SEP 13",
  "OCT 13"
]
```

Answer (score 0):

```ruby
require 'date'

def last_n_months(n, format='%^b %Y')
  (n+1).times.map { |i| (Date.today << i).strftime(format) }
end

last_n_months(12)
# => ["OCT 2013", "SEP 2013", "AUG 2013", "JUL 2013", "JUN 2013", "MAY 2013", "APR 2013", "MAR 2013", "FEB 2013", "JAN 2013", "DEC 2012", "NOV 2012", "OCT 2012"]
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, use of the `Date#methods` is the way to go here, and yes, they are needed to get today's date, but wouldn't it be more satisfying to roll-your-own? Here's one way:

```
# Assume start_year falls in current millenium. 1 <= start_month <= 12

MONTHS = %q[JAN FEB MAR APR MAY JUN JUL AUG SEP OCT NOV DEC].split

def doit(start_year, start_month)
  pairs = (((start_month-1)..11).to_a.product [start_year-1]) +
    ((0..(start_month-1)).to_a.product [start_year]) 
  pairs.map! {|p| MONTHS[p.first] + " #{p.last.to_s}"}.reverse
end

p doit(13, 10)
```

First create `pairs` =>

```
[[9, 12], [10, 12], [11, 12]] +
[[0, 13], [1, 13], [2, 13], [3, 13], [4, 13], [5, 13], [6, 13], [7, 13], [8, 13], [9, 13]]
```

which is

```
[[9, 12], [10, 12], [11, 12], [0, 13], [1, 13], [2, 13], [3, 13],
 [4, 13], [5, 13], [6, 13], [7, 13], [8, 13], [9, 13]]
```

Then replace elements of pairs with a string containing the month abbreviation and year.

```
["OCT 13", "SEP 13", "AUG 13", "JUL 13", "JUN 13", "MAY 13", "APR 13",
 "MAR 13", "FEB 13", "JAN 13", "DEC 12", "NOV 12", "OCT 12"]
```

I evidently need all the parentheses in calculating `pairs`.  Can anyone explain why I need the outer ones on the second line?